# Sum up ride_length for weekdays vs weekends and compare for casual and annual members

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, weekday, weekend

Hi Im a beginner in R so dont know much functionality to go about to perform this operation even though in my head i know what to do just dont know how to do it.

So I have data for of ride length I want to sum up for weekdays vs weekends and compare it with annual and casual members.
I have used the wday() to convert the dates to '1' to '7'. Now i want to filter out '2' to '6' (weekdays) and sum the ride_lenth and filter out '1' & '7' (weekends) and sum that ride_length and then use the aggregate() to compare them with the casual and annual members usage.
That is what i have decided.

```
member_type  ride_length     date    month     day       year      day_of_week      weekday_num

casual       5280        2020-07-01   Jul        01       2020         Wednesday              4
casual       9840        2020-07-01   Jul        01       2020         Wednesday              4
```

Any other path to this would be welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately I can not test the code due to missing input and desired output. But you should be able to make these lines work for you:

```
library(dplyr)

# your data.frame/tibble
df %>%
    # create variable to indicate weekend or not (check the weekend day names)
    dplyr::mutate(day_type = ifelse(day_of_week %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), "WEEKEND","WEEK")) %>%
    # build gouping by member type and day type
    dplyr::group_by(member_type, day_type) %>%
    # summarise total ride length
    dplyr::summarize(total_ride_length = sum(ride_length, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Just as an advice: possibly there are some holidays you should consider, as they can be on a working day but show the behaviour of a weekend day (due to most people having free time to rent and ride bikes or viceverse if people predominantly rent to get to and from work)

Comment: thanks alot i will try this out!
i need to check out the syntax of ifelse that youve used. 
aslo the four semicolons that youve used what does that mean? : : ? is it an assign function?

Comment: @SarthakDev the :: is used to call a function directly from a library but you do not need it if you already called the library itself... I keep anyhow to make sure that the used function stems from the correct library as sometimes libraries use the same function name but the function implementations differ. The ifelse() uses an %in% operator, which returns TRUE it the variable before the %in% is the same as one (or more) of the vector after the %in% operator.... and if not it returns FALSE. TRUE is the the second argument of ifelse() and FALSE the third

Comment: @SarthakDev please consider to accept my answers for others to know it has been solve. thx